# Is $f(x)=e^{x^Tx'}$ a suitable kernel to be choosen?

Tags: kernel-trick

Is $f(x)=e^{x^Tx'}$ a suitable kernel to be choosen? If so, to what dimension does it transform the data?

Comment: Kernel for *what*?  "Kernel" means [many different things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28mathematics%29#Mathematics) in mathematics and statistics.  Even the [tag:data-transformation] tag doesn't narrow the scope much!

Comment: @whuber: Right, sorry that I wasn't clear enough. I meant [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick) where $k(x,x')$ is referred to as a kernel or a kernel function.

Comment: What's the difference between $x^T$ and $x'$?

Comment: He means there's two different variables, $x$ and $x'$, and he's just taking their dot product.

Comment: I think he means $K(x,y)=e^{x^Ty}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mimshot: That's right. I mean $k(x,x')$ is a function of $x$ and $x'$ instead of $x$ and $y$ in $k(x,y)$. It's actually the same as explained in that Wikipedia article in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are referring to the kernel as a kernel in machine-learning literature, then yes, it is a kernel.

More generally, we can consider the family of Gaussian kernels, parametrized by $\sigma$:

$$K(x,x') = e^{x^Tx'/\sigma^2 }$$

Using the power series expansion of the function exponential, we can rewrite the expression of $K$ as:

$$ K(x, x') = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^T \cdot x' )^n}{\sigma^{2n}n!} $$

Recall kernels are closed under summation, even infinite sums. $K$ then is sum of other (polynomial) kernels , thus is still kernel. 
The polynomial kernel, $(x\cdot x')^d$ can be shown to map $x$ to monomials of degree $d$. Thus the Gaussian kernel maps $x$ to all the polynomial kernels.

Example:
In two dimensions, $x = (x_1,x_2), \; x' = (x_1', x_2')$, the secord order polynomial kernel $(x \cdot x')^2$ maps the data to look like a new inner product:

$$( x_1^2, x_2^2, x_1 x_2 ) \cdot (x_1'^2, x_2'^2, x_1' x_2')$$
The polynomial kernel is actually computing the above, which looks like it mapped $(x_1, x_2)$ to all monomials of degree 2. The Gaussian kernel does the same thing but for degree 1, degree 2, degree 3...

### Side Note

Often in ML literature, the Gaussian kernel is defined as

$$K'(x,x') = \exp{\Big( \frac{||x - x'||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) }$$

But this is actually the *normalized Gaussian kernel*. A normalized kernel, $K'$, is defined:

$$ K'(x,x') = \frac{K(x,x')}{\sqrt{ K(x,x) K(x',x') } } $$

If we use $K(x,x') = \exp{\Big( \frac{x^Tx'}{\sigma^2 } \Big) }$, we get:

$$ K'(x,x') = \frac{e^{x^Tx'/\sigma^2 }}{ \exp{ \Big(\frac{||x||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big)} \exp{\Big(\frac{||x'||^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big) } } $$

$$ = \exp{ \Big( -\frac{||x' - x||^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) }$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain yourself a little more - what do you mean by "maps x to all powers of x"?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to include a better explaination