# Proving the function is a kernel

Tags: kernel-trick

I have an exercise in my book, which I'm not sure if I have answered correctly. Here's the exercise:

For the function  $K: \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$K(x,t)=x^TDt$$, where $$D=\begin{pmatrix} -1 && 2 \\ 2 &&4  \end{pmatrix}$$

Determine whether the function is a valid kernel (i.e., the kernel can be written as an inner product in some feature space) and when the answer is positive derive an associated feature map representation.

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48506/what-function-could-be-a-kernel), it is said that we have to check that the funciton $k(x,t)$ is symmetric and also whether it is positive definite. So, the function is symmetric. We need to check if it's PSD.

We check it by inspecting for an "inner-product" representation. I would like to find a $\phi(a)$, such that $k(x,t)=\phi(x)^T\phi(t)$. Well, $$\phi(a)=(ia_1,\sqrt{2}a_1,\sqrt{2}a_2,2a_2)^T$$

Hence, $K$ is a valid kernel.

**EDIT**

There is no such function, because the indices in $K(x,t)=x^TDt=-x_1t_1+2x_2t_1+2x_1t_2+4x_2t_2$ are "mixed", i.e., $x_1$ is multiplied by $t_2$, so there is no such function $\phi(a)$.

**Hence $K$ is not a valid kernel.**

> Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: What is $K((1,0), (1,0))$?

Comment: @whuber it's $-1$, yes I know that it's less than $0$ hence it doesn't satisfy the conditions of an inner product space, positive definiteness in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking $K((1,0), (1,0)) < 0$ rules out that the possibility that it can be a kernel.

Checking whether $x^TDx$ is a valid kernel is equivalent to checking if $D$ is positive semidefinite.

Mixing indices can occur in matrix in the expression of $K(x,t)$, for example if $D=\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$, then $K$ is a valid kernel since it is positive semidefnite.

Comment: When you say that checking whether $K(x,y)$ is a kernel is a question of whether $D$ is positive SD. But why is that so? I know that if $D$ is psd then $K$ is a kernel, but why would the converse be true?

Comment: Suppose $D$ is not positive semidefinite, then it is possible to find $x$ such that $x^TDx < 0$, which violate Mercer's theorem.

Comment: oh yes, that's true. thanks for the answer!